# Random real antisymmetric matrix

Tags: matrix, random

Is there a way to create random real antisymmetric matrix in Mathematica. Please see the example of such a matrix.
[image: cc]

Comment: `n = 10 ; a = RandomReal[{0.0, 1.0}, {n, n}] ; b = 0.5*(a - Transpose[a]) ; AntisymmetricMatrixQ[b]`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Nop

Comment: How do you want the entries distributed?  The simplest option would be a uniform distribution between some upper bound & lower bound for all of the independent entries, but other options exist.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version which allows you to specify a distribution and only generates the required number of random draws for a symmetric matrix. You could replace the `RandomVariate[...]` code with something like `RandomInterger[]` if you'd like.

```
(*Dimension*)
n = 3;

(*Distribution*)
dist = NormalDistribution[];

(*Construct upper triangular SparseArray, efficiently only creating n*(n-1)/2 random numbers.*)
s = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i < j :> RandomVariate[dist], {n, n}];

(*Create antisymmetric matrix.*)
m = Normal[s - Transpose[s]];

AntisymmetricMatrixQ[m]
(*True*)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the distribution of generated matrices:

````
m = RandomInteger[{0, 50}, {3, 3}];
result = m - Transpose[m]

AntisymmetricMatrixQ[result]  (* True *)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SymmetrizedArray` to create arrays with any kind of symmetry:

```
Normal @ SymmetrizedArray[
  RandomInteger[10, {3, 3}],
  Automatic,
  Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]
]
```